# extract value of a query parameter in varnish

Tags: regex, caching, varnish, query-string

I have this url:

`http://my.api.com/v1/{api_key}/{user_token}/?someparam=hello&force=true&someotherparam=world`

where `api_key` and `user_token` are uuids

How do I extract the value of the `force` query param, and either do a lookup from varnish cache if the force param is missing OR it is set to false. If it is set to true, I need to hit my backend server. Query params can be in any order.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you inverse the logic:

```
sub vcl_recv { 
    if (req.url ~ "(?i)force=(true|yes)") {
        return(pass);
    }
    // other values will fall through to the safe default VCL that will do return(lookup).
}
```

Comment: How about using: `set req.hash_always_miss = true;` as suggested at: https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleEnableForceRefresh

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Ikarsten's answer, but not matching the xxxtoken parameter.

```
sub vcl_recv { 
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|\&)token=") {
        return(pass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your vcl_recv you can check for non-existant force= or force=true with something like:

```
 if(!req.url ~ "&|\?force=" || req.url ~ "&|\?force=true") {
     return(pass);
 }
```

Comment: This forced lookup skips the authorization and cookie checks that are done in the default VCL, and as such is a bit dangerous if any of those are in use. You can end up caching user specific data with this. Falling through to the default VCL is always recommended.

Comment: I did not pretend to write a full vcl_recv configuration, but try to answer the question posed. Any rules that this should play well with, be it the default rules or not, should naturally be considered. Trying to write a complete safe config without knowing the current config is impossible.